# Trying to set a move in tic tac toe game, but I keep getting undefined when I call back the function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm calling my function with `addEventListener` down at the bottom, but for some reason my `setMove` function is giving me undefined. I'm trying to put a 'X' or an 'O' on one of the buttons when clicked, and the way I'm doing that is setting my variable `buttonClicked` which will give me the DOM object, then I iterate through the object and that's where I get stuck. I'm not sure what to do after that. I'm a beginner in JavaScript, so please take it easy on me.  Thank you in advance!!! :)

HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrap">

    <div id="board">
        <h2>Tic Tac Toe</h2>
        <div>
          <button class="btn"></button>
          <button class="btn"></button>
          <button class="btn"></button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <button class="btn"></button>
          <button class="btn"></button>
          <button class="btn"></button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <button class="btn"></button>
          <button class="btn"></button>
          <button class="btn"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gameOutput"></div>


    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var players = ['X', 'O'];
    var currentMove = 0;
    var gameOver = false;
    var output = document.querySelector('#gameOutput');
    var buttonClicked = document.querySelectorAll('#board .btn');


    output.innerText = "Game is ready. " + players[currentMove] + " Turn.";


    // sets X or O
    var setMove = function (move, mark) {
        for (var i = 0; i < move.length; i++) {
            move[i].innertText = mark;
        }
    };


    //some code

    var buttonClickHandler = function() {

    //some more code

    if (valid(buttonClicked) === true) {
                this.style.backgroundColor = '#0D771A';
                console.log(setMove(buttonClicked, players[currentMove]));
            } else if (valid(button) === false) {
                output.innerText = "That is not a valid move :(";
            };

    //some more code
    });

    for (var i = 0;i < buttonClicked.length; i++) {
            buttonClicked[i].addEventListener('click', buttonClickHandler);
    }
```

Comment: The setMove method is not returning any value... that is the reason... what do you want to be logged hen calling `setMove`

Comment: can you recreate your problem in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dk5tLgnq/1/)

Comment: on this line `//some more code});` right before the last for statement remove the `)`

Comment: quick question: Did you mean `move[i].innerText = mark` instead of `move[i].innertText = mark`?

Comment: 1. Why isn't your JS code wrapped in script tags? 2. Isn't `innertText` a typo? 3. Braces don't make sense. 4. How could setMove give you undefined when it doesn't call any functions and doesn't return anything?

Comment: check out my whole code here [link](http://repl.it/v65)

Comment: so what's the problem @FernandoGomez, your code seems ok, no errors!! Is your problem with the logic or what??

Comment: @Dropout thank you for pointing that out. I spent ours trying to figure it out, and that was one of the problems. It still gives me undefined though but at least I'm able to get set the move in the buttons. It sets all of the buttons, and I still have to find out where is the problem.

Comment: @KAD yes the problem is with the logic...How can I get the moves into my squares, but at the same time when somebody clicks the square that's already been clicked come out with an invalid move, and then come out with a winner or a draw.

Comment: @Dropout my JS is not wrapped in script tags because I'm calling it from my HTML with a link and adding an EventListener to my .js file. At least, that's what I was told to do it because it loaded the DOM first and then JS.

Comment: @FernandoGomez it looks like one file in your question. I've edited it so it's clear that those are two files.

Comment: Here's a better link [link](http://codepen.io/fher/pen/JdLKwz) so you can look at my code better.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra bracket after defining the `buttonClickHandler` function.
Besides, you are using a function `valid` that is not defined.. Please add it to the question if it's there or define it yourself and try again.

```
    var buttonClickHandler = function() {

        //some more code

        if (valid(buttonClicked) === true) {
                    this.style.backgroundColor = '#0D771A';
                    console.log(setMove(buttonClicked, players[currentMove]));
                } else if (valid(button) === false) {
                    output.innerText = "That is not a valid move :(";
                } // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< removing semi-colon

        //some more code
        }; //  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< removing extra bracket
```